# How in groovy (java) automatically find out the json field type and return values from json, replacing null with empty space?

Tags: java, arraylist, groovy, jsonslurper

The question is still relevant!

In my task, json comes to my input, which I do not know in advance. I need to collect all json field types into "types" and return all values ​​using `reader.outputLines`. Now the list of json field types is formed like this:
`def types = list.find (). Values ​​() *. GetClass () *. SimpleName`
But I am faced with a problem when the same field in the first json block is null, and in the second the integer and the type is defined as null, and not as Integer.

1. How to make sure that the type is determined by going through all the json blocks for each field, and not making an output based on the first block, and if everything is null or "" (empty), assign the default String?
2. When returning values ​​from json using `reader.outputLines`, replace null with "" (empty)?

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import ru.itrpro.xm.plugins.groovy.ResultSetReader;

class XM_PARSE_XLS {

    def execute(ResultSetReader reader, String pfile) {

        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        def list = jsonSlurper.parseText pfile

        List names = list.inject( new LinkedHashSet<>() ){ res, map ->
            res.addAll map.keySet()
            res
        }.toList()
        def types = list.find().values()*.getClass()*.simpleName

        //formation of the dataset header
        reader.outputLinesSetHeaders(names,types);

        list.each{ e ->
            reader.outputLines names.collect{ e[ it ] }
            //println names.collect{ e[ it ] }
        }

        //closing dataset
        reader.outputLinesEnd();
        return null;

    }
    static void main(String... args) {
        String pfile =  """
[{"AUTO":"bmw",
  "HOME":null,
  "JOB":""},
  
  {"AUTO":"audi",
  "HOME":135,
  "JOB":null},
  
  {"AUTO":"opel1",
  "HOME":10,
  "JOB":null}]
"""
        def SSC = new XM_PARSE_XLS()
        def res = SSC.execute(new ResultSetReader(), pfile)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following strategy: Iterate as long over the rows until
you know each type or you reach some sort of end (depending on the
amount of rows, you might want to just look in all rows or just give up
after N rows).  For each row try to determine the type and keep book of
the type, but only "promote" from `null` to the type in your bookkeeping.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic

def data = new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText("""
[{"AUTO":"bmw",   "HOME":null, "JOB":""},
 {"AUTO":"audi",  "HOME":135,  "JOB":null},
 {"AUTO":"opel1", "HOME":10,   "JOB":null}]
""")

def types = [:]
def it = data.iterator() // or only take(10) e.g.
while (it.hasNext() && !(types && types.every{ _, v -> v })) {
    it.next().collectEntries{ k, v -> 
        [k, v?.getClass()?.simpleName] 
    }.inject(types, { m, entry ->
        if (entry.value!=null || !m.containsKey(entry.key)) {
            m[entry.key] = entry.value
        }
        return m
    })
}

// if there are types missing (values with null), replace them here with
// your default)

println types
// → [AUTO:String, JOB:String, HOME:Integer]
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. When playing the code, an error like this occurs: 'do while' is not supported in current version
And judging by the description, the output goes "Typles: Value", and I need separate "types" to form the dataset header and use reader.outputLinesSetHeaders and separately "values" to use "reader.outputLines". I misunderstood the code a bit.

Comment: Do / while is not used in groovy, apparently

Comment: Do/while was added in 3 IIRC. If you are stuck on an old version, you can rewrite to just a while.  And yes, above code calculates the types and stores the result in map.

Comment: The code should work on the server, and there is no way to change the version

Comment: "does not work" does not help a bit. i rewrite the loop

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't figure it out. I tried to change the code, but I do not understand it, since I have not encountered similar tasks yet. The fact is that I cannot use the "ResultSetReader", because it requires collecting only field types in "types", and passing the values themselves into "reader.outputLines", as shown in my example. In your answer, "types" contains both types and values, so I cannot use "ResultSetReader".

Comment: Можно как-то в types собрать только типы, а значения отдельно, как в моем примере?
types: ["String", "String", "Integer"]

Comment: And the json order is out of order. In my example I am using
new LinkedHashSet <> () to store names and types in the desired order. If it does not make it difficult, can you suggest how to correctly collect separately names, types and values for using the ResultSetReader, as in my example?